# Partition data, detect value change in column, and ADD new COLUMN with DATE of change

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

###### Given the *data* **below**, I would like to:

- [x] Partition data by *device*
- [x] Report back details of the *latest reading*
- [ ] Add a *new* field capturing the date of the latest *device state* change

| id | device | date_observation | device_state | reading |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021100 | A | 2021-10-14 00:00:00.000 | 1 | -0.3623 |
| 2021101 | B | 2021-10-14 00:00:00.000 | 1 | -0.0004 |
| 2021102 | C | 2021-10-14 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0.1333 |
| 2021103 | A | 2021-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0.1907 |
| 2021104 | B | 2021-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 2 | -0.3548 |
| 2021105 | C | 2021-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 | -0.2275 |
| 2021106 | A | 2021-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2 | -0.2404 |
| 2021107 | B | 2021-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 2 | -0.0244 |
| 2021108 | C | 2021-10-28 00:00:00.000 | 1 | -0.3441 |
| 2021109 | A | 2021-11-04 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 0.2843 |
| 2021110 | B | 2021-11-04 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 0.2376 |
| 2021111 | C | 2021-11-04 00:00:00.000 | 1 | -0.0247 |
| 2021112 | A | 2021-11-11 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 0.1814 |
| 2021113 | B | 2021-11-11 00:00:00.000 | 3 | -0.2816 |
| 2021114 | C | 2021-11-11 00:00:00.000 | 1 | -0.1493 |
| 2021115 | A | 2021-11-18 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 0.1694 |
| 2021116 | B | 2021-11-18 00:00:00.000 | 4 | 0.0864 |
| 2021117 | C | 2021-11-18 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0.0395 |
| 2021118 | A | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 0.0658 |
| 2021119 | B | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 4 | 0.1291 |
| 2021120 | C | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2 | -0.1907 |

Using the code below, I am able partition data by device and to grab the latest record for each device.

```
WITH o AS (
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by device
                       ORDER BY date_observation DESC) AS queue
FROM observations  
)

SELECT *
FROM o
WHERE queue = 1
```

#### Results

| id | device | date_observation | device_state | reading | queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021118 | A | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 0.0658 | 1 |
| 2021119 | B | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 4 | 0.1291 | 1 |
| 2021120 | C | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2 | -0.1907 | 1 |

#### What is the best way to get the date of the latest state change?

For example the latest device state changed for device A occurred on 2021-10-28.

##### The expected output.

| id | device | date_observation | device_state | reading | queue | date_state_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021118 | A | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2 | 0.0658 | 1 | 2021-10-28 |
| 2021119 | B | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 4 | 0.1291 | 1 | 2021-11-18 |
| 2021120 | C | 2021-11-25 00:00:00.000 | 2 | -0.1907 | 1 | 2021-11-25 |

Thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML (or a DB Fiddle) you make it *much* easier for people to assist.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I don't have enough "stackoverflow" mojo to vote the answers up, but was able to use pieces from two the answers provided to solve my actual coding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you a solution built on your first part (I adpated it as I would have built the query) and a flow to calculate the latest state's change, whith the following steps:

- add on each row the previous state
- add an indicator of state's change
- calculate max date for rows identified as state's change
- join the result to yours

Here is the result I propose:

```sql
WITH prev_data AS (
  SELECT id, device, date_observation, device_state, reading,
         LAG(device_state) OVER (partition by device order by date_observation) as prev_state
    FROM observations
),
data_changes AS (
  SELECT id, device, date_observation, device_state, reading,
         CASE WHEN device_state = prev_state THEN 0 else 1 END as change_state
    FROM prev_data
),
last_change AS (
  SELECT device, max(date_observation) as date_state_change
    FROM data_changes
   WHERE change_state = 1
   GROUP BY device
),
max_date as (
    SELECT id, device, date_observation, device_state, reading,
           max(date_observation) over (partition by device) as max_date
      FROM observations
)
SELECT id, m.device, date_observation, device_state, reading, date_state_change
  FROM max_date m
  LEFT JOIN last_change l ON m.device = l.device
 WHERE date_observation = max_date
```

Result :

```
  id     device     date_observation         device_state      reading         date_state_change
2021118     A    2021-11-25 00:00:00.000          2            0.0658       2021-10-28 00:00:00.000
2021119     B    2021-11-25 00:00:00.000          4            0.1291       2021-11-18 00:00:00.000
2021120     C    2021-11-25 00:00:00.000          2            -0.1907      2021-11-25 00:00:00.000
```

You can check the result using [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57cf6af03717bfb11e7209613206a555)

Answer (score 1):

You can use more window functions

- Use `LEAD` to identify the change-over rows
- Use `MAX` to get the latest change-over date

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      queue = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY date_observation DESC),
      date_state_change = CASE WHEN device_state <>
            LEAD(device_state, 1, -1) OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY date_observation DESC)
            THEN date_observation END
    FROM observations o
),
MaxValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      max_date_state_change = MAX(date_state_change) OVER (PARTITION BY device)
    FROM PrevValues o
)
SELECT
  o.id,
  o.device,
  o.date_observation,
  o.device_state,
  o.reading,
  o.queue,
  o.max_date_state_change
FROM MaxValues o
WHERE o.queue = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97ddae4ed42e6a98116932237189582c)

Comment: Does your `CASE` statement mean that, if the condition is not met, the row is not selected? Anyway, much more compact than my solution, even if the process is the same, I'm impressed by the simplicity =)

Comment: No it's just returning `ELSE NULL`, and `MAX` will ignore nulls. Window functions are the solution to a lot of such analytic questions

Comment: OK, thanks for the precision, very nice to know the default behavior. And yes, I fully agree!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LAG() to compare current row device_state and the previous row device state for each device and use MAX() to get the date_state_change.

```
WITH
f1 AS (
SELECT *, MAX(date_observation) OVER (PARTITION BY device) AS max_date,
       CASE WHEN device_state <> LAG(device_state) OVER (PARTITION BY device ORDER BY date_observation) 
       THEN date_observation END AS date_flag
FROM observations
),
f2 AS (
SELECT *, MAX(date_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY device) AS date_state_change
FROM f1
)
SELECT id, device, date_observation, device_state, reading, date_state_change  
FROM f2
WHERE max_date = date_observation;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2290ce87219adf010a98e45887039d4c)